# SQL Server - Convert table data to xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Hi I have the following table data I need to convert to Xml in SQl Server. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

From

```
Party_Id  HomePhoneNumber  WorkPhoneNumber
62356     6314993578    
62356                      6314590922
62356                      6313795488
```

To

```
<HomePhoneNumber>6314993578</HomePhoneNumber>
<WorkPhoneNumber>6314590922</WorkPhoneNumber>
<WorkPhoneNumber>6313795488</WorkPhoneNumber>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the empty values into NULLs.  These NULL values will be excluded from the XML.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Party_Id int,HomePhoneNumber varchar(25),WorkPhoneNumber varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(62356,'6314993578',''),    
(62356,'','6314590922'),
(62356,'','6313795488')

Select HomePhoneNumber=case when HomePhoneNumber='' then null else HomePhoneNumber end 
      ,WorkPhoneNumber=case when WorkPhoneNumber='' then null else WorkPhoneNumber end  
 From  @YourTable 
 For   XML Path('')
```

Returns

```
<HomePhoneNumber>6314993578</HomePhoneNumber>
<WorkPhoneNumber>6314590922</WorkPhoneNumber>
<WorkPhoneNumber>6313795488</WorkPhoneNumber>
```